# Javascript parameter inside an other parameter

Tags: javascript

What does it mean when you have a parameter inside an other parameter in a function?

For example:

```
var c = function (a,b) {
    a(b);
};
```

What does `a(b)`do?

Comment: You should regard `()` as a postfix operator, that can be applied to *anything* that has a value.

Answer (score 2):

We know that an expression of the form `f(x)` is a call to the function `f` taking a single argument `x`. In addition, JS allows us to pass function callbacks as parameters to other functions. For instance:

```
function callback(x) { alert(x); }

c(callback, 5);
```

The callback takes a single argument, and that other argument `5` is passed as a parameter to the callback. In turn, it alerts the number.

Comment: How does this relate to JavaScript's weak type system?

Comment: @phant0m Because we can never actually know the type of the parameter. Unlike in strictly typed languages like C++ where we can restrict all but a function pointer (callback) to be passed.

Comment: You can make that argument for every function and its argument--no matter whether they are supposed to be functions or not--you define in JavaScript, why is this worth pointing out here? That is the part I don't understand.

Comment: Because normally i would expect arguments to be literals or variables, not an actual function. Thats what got me when i started learning this

Comment: You're making an artificial distinction here. You always pass objects, never variables. -- I like the new wording much better, +1.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `c` is a function that can be passed two objects, `a` and `b`. From the definition it looks like `a` should be a function object and `b` a parameter for that function.

Within the definition you have a function called `a` being passed an argument of the object `b`.

Find out more about [functions in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Comment: Thanks, is there any advantage of using that instead of this:var c = function (b) {
    function a (b){};
};

Comment: The advantage of your original example would be that you could pass any function object to `c` and it would run it. In your example here in the comments, the only function that can be run is the one defined inside the function definition for `c`. One is not better than the other, it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

This means that `a` should be a function which gets executed when it's passed to `c`, along with another argument.

[An example of usage:](http://jsfiddle.net/x6qpq/1/)

```
//c accepts a function and an argument
c(function(theSentB){
  //this passed function gets executed due to a(b);
  //and 'hello' is passed to it

  alert(theSentB);

},'hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript treats functions as a first class objects. This means that you can pass function as parameters. (it is a little like delegates in C#)

In your case, `a` is a parameter that points to a function and you execute it inside the function represented by c . (`a`  itself, using `b` as it's first argument).